# I have insert the integers 1,1 in arraylist c,but when I printing the c arraylist .it is howing empty,why?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList();
    int a1=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<a1;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("enter Elements");
        a.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    int b1=sc.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> b=new ArrayList();
    for(int j=0;j<b1;j++)
    {
        System.out.println("enter elemets for b");
        b.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> c=new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(i>j)
                c.add(1);
            if(i<j)
                c.add(1);   
        }
    }       
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

In Java console -->

```
3
enter Elements
1
enter Elements
2
enter Elements
3
3
enter elemets for b
3
enter elemets for b
2
enter elemets for b
1
[]
```

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Answer (score 3):

The issue comes with the non-sense loop

```
for(int j=i;j<=i;j++){
    if(i>j)
        c.add(1);
    if(i<j)
        c.add(1);   
}
```

1. You define `j=i`
2. check if `j` is **strictly** superior or inferior to `i` : none are True
3. increment `j`, `j<=i` is now False, the loops ends

Conclusion : that for-loop does nothing